# NVL function in scala on dataframe join select operation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can join dataframes in scala like this and it works;

```
  df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"), "left").select(df1("id"),df2("name"))
```

I want to use **nvl** function on df2.name column like **nvl(df2.name,"test")**

How can I handle this with spark scala ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalece and lit from spark.sql.functions

```
df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"), "left").select(df1("id"),coalesce(df2("name"),lit("test")))
```